# AdMob banner disappears after i reopen the app

Tags: ios, ipad, storyboard, admob, banner

I have a view controller (iPad only) with a banner view implemented using storyboard (I followed the official tutorial).

The ads load fine, the only problem is when I close the app (multitasking): when I reopen it the ad view disappears and doesn't show any ads.

This is happening even with test ads.

My project uses Swift, Xcode 7.2 and AdMob SDK 7.2.0

Comment: I also observed this problem in obj.C iPhone games.

Comment: @NatureFriend at least I'm not the only one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

This happens only if your app support Split View.

The easy fix is to disable Split View by enabling "Requires full screen"

[image]

Comment: How to solve this issue when you want to support Split View though.